# "If" function used for array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have this function:

```
def q(x,y):
    r2 = (x/2.)**2 + (2.0*y)**2
    if (r2 > 0.04): 
        return 0.
    else:
        return 1.5
```

and I want to call it using something like

```
from pylab import *
dl=0.025
X, Y = mgrid[-0.5:0.5:dl, -0.5:0.5:dl]
g(X,Y)
```

but obviously this gives an error in the comparison.

Can this be done without having to make a for cycle for X and Y?
Because if I want to call q(x,y) for two doubles, the for cycle must be reimplemented for that case...

**Edit:**  (Adding this to the question as it is too long for a comment and not an answer, but it may help others answer.)

It appears `pylab.mgrid` is the same as `numpy.mgrid`.

Adjusted for `numpy`, this code

```
import numpy
def q(x,y):
    r2 = (x/2.)**2 + (2.0*y)**2
    if (r2 > 0.04): 
        return 0.
    else:
        return 1.5

dl=0.025
X, Y = numpy.mgrid[-0.5:0.5:dl, -0.5:0.5:dl]
q(X,Y)
```

gives this error

```
    if (r2 > 0.04):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: I don't know pylab so.. what exactly is in `r2` and what do you want to do with it? If it is an array - what is it you want to compare? All elements must satisfy the condition or ..?

Comment: r2 is r^2 of an ellipsis... g(X,Y) should be an mgrid like but with values evaluated on every point of X,Y.

Comment: Please tell us what object `mgrid` is: `print repr(mgrid)` for a small example.

Comment: mgrid is: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `r2 > 0.04` evaluates to a NumPy array of Boolean values, so you can't use it in an `if` statement.  You can have it automatically reinterpreted as numbers, though:

```
def q(x,y):
    r2 = (x/2.)**2 + (2.0*y)**2
    return 1.5 * (r2 <= 0.04)
```

Comment: It is not the most general solution, but it solves the problem for this specific problem. Do you know a way of avoiding this for more cases (more if's else's etc.)

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: The specifics of how to vectorize a particular piece of code depend on the specifics of the code.  In this particular example, it is comparitively simple, in other cases it is harder and sometimes it is impossible.  The given technique can usually be extended to multiple `if` statements, possibly by using the `&` and `|` operators or partial assigment `r2[r2 > 0.04] = ...`.

Comment: Ok. Thank you Sven for the idea and knowledge shared.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) to apply your function to each couple of elements.

Comment: In the given context, this answer is wrong.  `X` and `Y` are two-dimensional arrays, so the `zip()` would produce pairs of rows, so the problem still isn't solved.  Moreover, the whole point of NumPy is to avoid this kind of Python loop over all elements.

Comment: Ok, I removed the non-working code. But the spirit of my answer was just to suggest 'map' as a possible way of resolving the issue; it didn't meant to be the most efficient solution.

Comment: Removed my downvote because the answer is no longer wrong.  Honsetly, I think it's still not particularly helpful, though.